# database.models.Employee is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?

Tags: java, playframework, persistence, h2

I'm trying to use Play Framework with h2 database, using Ebeans, to create a simple employee management site, but I just can't seem to get it working. The error I've been hit with is:

`Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: database.models.Employee is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?`

So the obvious conclusion is that the Employee class isn't an entity, according to Ebeans. I've followed the documentation for the most part and the Employee class has been built exactly as it shows.

```
package database.models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import io.ebean.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Employees")
public class Employee extends Model {

@Transient
public static final Finder<Long, Employee> find = new Finder<>(Employee.class);

@Id
long emp_id;
@Constraints.Required
String name;

public Employee() {

}
```

App.conf

```
db {

default.driver=org.h2.Driver

default.url="jdbc:h2:file:./data/employeeDB.mv.db.mv.db"

default.username = admin

default.password = pass


}

ebean.default=["models.*"]
```

And build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false

libraryDependencies += guice

libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.192" 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)
```

I'm using IntelliJ and I've used practically every tool it has to confirm that the class is working alright. It appears in the Persistence Tool Window as an entity and I've set the datasource to the H2 database connection that I've made. As for the properties on the H2 database connection:

Path: `./data/employeeDB/mv.db.mv.db`
URL: `jdbc:h2:file:./data/employeeDB.mv.db.mv.db`

It doesn't seem to mind either of those, and the username and password are all right. I can use this connection to run SQL just fine, but as soon as it comes to actual persistence is when the errors arise, so I don't think it's due to the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model "Employee" seems to be in a package called `database.models;`

Could you try to change the `ebean.default` setting to `["database.models.*"]`

Comment: I tried changing it to `["database.models.*"]` but the error now reads `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Table "EMPLOYEES" not found; SQL statement:` . I tried removing a character from the path to make it invalid, but it's still throwing the same exception, which probably means that `["database.models.*"]` is invalid.

Comment: that's odd. can you check if the table 'EMPLOYEES' does exist? do you have the evolutions plugin enabled for generating the sql scripts which will be applied in your database?

Comment: Good news, I found out what was wrong. The problem was related to evolutions. Evolutions was trying to execute the SQL scripts in order, so 1.sql, 2.sql... But I'd already written 1.sql myself, so evolutions couldn't generate anything over it. It just assumed I had the right code. Once I renamed 1.sql to 2.sql evolutions kicked in and built the right file for me.